# jQuery не понимает селектор li:hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```js
$("li:hover").prev("li:first").css("border-top-right-radius","15px");
```

При наведении на `li`, он не срабатывает.
Почему?

Comment: А как Вы себе представляете "взять состояние, а не элемент"?

Comment: Какая есть альтернатива?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что псевдокласс селектора `:hover` описывает **состояние**, которое не может быть выбрано как элемент.

Вы можете выбрать элемент, и отслеживать на нем **событие** наведения курсора.
Для отслеживания наведения, в jQuery есть функция [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```js
$('li').hover(function (e) {  
  highlight.call($(this), true);
}, function (e) {
  highlight.call($(this), false);
});

function highlight (isIn = true) {
  let prev = this.prev();
  let next = this.next();
  
  if (prev.length > 0 && prev.prop('tagName') === 'LI') {
    prev.css({color: isIn ? 'red' : 'black'});
  }
  if (next.length > 0 && next.prop('tagName') === 'LI') {
    next.css({color: isIn ? 'green' : 'black'});
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span>1.</span> First</li>
  <li><span>2.</span> Second</li>
  <li><span>3.</span> Third</li>
  <li><span>4.</span> Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Мне нужна подсветка 1.First и 3.Third при наведении на 2.Second, подсветка 2.Second и 4.Fourth при наведении на 3.Third и т.д.

Comment: @Igor, задача "Подсветить при наведении" выходит за рамки вопроса "почему не работает ...". Если Вы хотите получить помощь в решении этой задачи - пожалуйста, оформите ее отдельным (качественным) вопросом.

Comment: @Igor, Подправил, но исключительно потому что я добряк :) Смысл-то я донёс, а дальше сами.